# How to fill an array with all the bit combinations for 1 byte?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bit

Say I have an array like `String[] arrayofbits = new String[256];`

I would like to generate an array of 256 indexes. Starting from index 0, which would be `arrayofbits[0] = "00000000"` index 1 `arrayofbits[1] = "00000001"` and so on to 255th index `arrayofbits[255] = 11111111`. How to generate it?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If so, post the code here and explain specifically what is not working. If not, give it a shot first.

Comment: `a[i]=i` Am I missing anything?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes. you are missing the fact that the OP does not know how to write a loop.

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey I was a bit confused, so I wanted some guidance to get me started.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I wasn't very clear with my question, sorry.
@ MikeNakis Thank you for your "constructive" criticism. I hoped someone would point out my mistakes rather can berate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to code a solution. Maybe I wasn't too clear with my problem, anyway thank you all who helped me.

```
  String[] arrayofbits = new String[256];
  byte bytes;
  String s;

  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

   bytes = (byte) i;

   s = (Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & bytes)).replaceAll(".*(.{8})$", "$1");
   s = StringUtils.leftPad(s, 8, "0");
   arrayofbits[i] = s;
   System.out.println("index " + i + " " + s + "\n");


  }
```

Comment: This doesn't actually do what you stated in your question, since there's no array being filled in. Can you update the question to make clearer what you actually want to do?

Comment: My bad, I didn't copy the right edits, now its updated.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<256; i++ ) {
    arrayofbits[i] = i; //because everything is binary!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
String asString = Integer.toBinaryString(32);
```

to convert a byte to a binary string. That is, `32` becomes `100000`.

If you then want to convert the string `"111"` to the decimal value `111` you can use:

```
int asDecimal = Integer.valueOf("111");
```

which returns `111` (one hundred and eleven).

However, I assume that you only care about the first part (converting `"111"` to `111` doesn't make a lot of sense to me).